# How to remove formulas and keep values in every row IF a specific cell of the row is NOT empty?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I'm building a spreadsheet to keep track of attendance.

Column B is data validated from a DB table in another sheet. Columns D, E, F, G pull data from the same DB table using XLOOKUP based on the name on column B.

PROBLEM: If something in the DB table changes, like the account number of a person, every past attendance of that person is updated.

Example
[image]

I need to "lock" the data in cells that have been filled, although they should accept manual editing.

So far I'm tryng to put a button somewhere on the sheet that deletes all formulas but keeps that value of the cells. I did some googling and got this:

```vb
Sub Remove_Formulas_from_Selected_Range()

Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Selection

Rng.Copy

Rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

How do I adapt the button so it checks every row of the table, and if the Column B of that row is NOT empty (meaning the row is filled with a person's data) only THEN deletes the formulas of that row and keeps the values.

Answer (score 0):

Your file must be an .xlsm file. Add an ActiveX button.  Double click on it.
Inside the created button_click() sub add one line: call doTheJob
-After paste code below:

```
Private Sub doTheJob()
   Dim rng As Range, rw As Long, c As Long
   If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
      If MsgBox("Change formulas with Values in selected range?", vbDefaultButton2 + vbExclamation + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
         Set rng = Selection
         rw = rng.Rows.CountLarge
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         For c = 1 To rw
            If Trim(rng.Cells(c, 2).Value) <> "" Then
               rng.Rows(c).Copy
               rng.Rows(c).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            End If
         Next
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Before click the button you must select the range you interest to replace the formulas with the values.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Is there a way to just check the whole document (or table) instead of having to select the range? Having to select the range is a step that some people will just forget or find "too complicated". I need the button to do both steps at once.

Answer (score 0):

This sub is for a sheet's module and one "fixed" table name

Private Sub doTheJob()
Dim rng As Range, rw As Long, c As Long
If MsgBox("Change formulas with Values in selected range?", vbDefaultButton2 + vbExclamation + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
Set rng = Me.ListObjects("NameOfTable").Range
rw = rng.Rows.CountLarge
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For c = 1 To rw
If Trim(rng.Cells(c, 2).Value) <> "" Then
rng.Rows(c).Copy
rng.Rows(c).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End If
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
End Sub

Use this code when the range is a Table. Modify the "NameOfTable" to the real name of your table.

This sub is for the Workbook an have to copy in a module inside folder "Modules". In sheets you wand to call this, add an ActiceX button and call the sub like below:

[image: screen of the example]

```
Public Sub doTheJob(ws As Worksheet, tablename As String)
   Dim rng As Range, rw As Long, c As Long
   
   If (Not ws Is Nothing) And tablename <> "" Then
      Set rng = ws.ListObjects(tablename).Range
   Else
      MsgBox ("call the doTheJob with prameters a worksheet and a table name")
      Exit Sub
   End If
   If Not rng Is Nothing Then
      If MsgBox("Change formulas with Values in range " & tablename & " ?", vbDefaultButton2 + vbExclamation + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
         rw = rng.Rows.CountLarge
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         For c = 1 To rw
            If Trim(rng.Cells(c, 2).Value) <> "" Then
               rng.Rows(c).Copy
               rng.Rows(c).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            End If
         Next
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
      End If
   Else
      MsgBox ("doTheJob> Invalid table name")
   End If
End Sub

'This sub is in sheets module 
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Call doTheJob(Me, Range("TABLE_NAMES").Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: It says "invalid use of Me".